# Unable to create virtual device

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation

I have Android Studio 3.3. I am trying to create virtual device. I installed lollipop on pixel XL. But I get this error:
Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+.

How do I solve this

Answer (score 0):

Open android studio -> Select tools SDK Manager -> Select SDK Tools -> Install/update Android SDK Tools and Android SDK Platform